# Fields show it's empty although there is data inside it

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm using WordPress, I customized a form in it but my added fields show empty message although there is data inside it...

The problem is on those three fields "date, pax and cabin" the rest is working well...
You can check this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck1d6.jpg)

```
add_action('wp_ajax_st_send_email_single_service', 'st_send_email_single_service');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_st_send_email_single_service', 'st_send_email_single_service');
function st_send_email_single_service() {
$type_service = isset($_GET['type_service']) ? $_GET['type_service'] : '';
$name_service = isset($_GET['name_service']) ? $_GET['name_service'] : '';
$name_st = isset($_GET['name_st']) ? $_GET['name_st'] : '';
$email_st = isset($_GET['email_st']) ? $_GET['email_st'] : '';
$phone_st = isset($_GET['phone_st']) ? $_GET['phone_st'] : '';
$date = isset($_GET['date']) ? $_GET['date'] : '';

$pax = isset($_GET['pax']) ? $_GET['pax'] : '';
$cabin = isset($_GET['cabin']) ? $_GET['cabin'] : '';
$content_st = isset($_GET['content_st']) ? $_GET['content_st'] : '';
$email_owl = isset($_GET['email_owl']) ? $_GET['email_owl'] : '';
$status = 0;
$message = '';
$subject_st = $name_st . ' - ' . $email_st;
if (empty($name_st) || (empty($email_st)) || (empty($phone_st)) || (empty($date)) || (empty($pax)) || (empty($cabin)) || (empty($content_st))) {
    $status = 0;
    if (empty($name_st)) {
        $message .= __('Please enter your name', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) . '<br>';
    }
    if (empty($email_st)) {
        $message .= __('Please enter your mail', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) . '<br>';
    }
    if (empty($phone_st)) {
        $message .= __('Please enter your phone', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) . '<br>';
    }
    if (empty($date)) {
        $message .= __('Please enter the date of the trip', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) . '<br>';
    }
    if (empty($pax)) {
        $message .= __('Please enter the number of persons', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) . '<br>';
    }
    if (empty($cabin)) {
        $message .= __('Please enter your cabin requests', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) . '<br>';
    }
    if (empty($content_st)) {
        $message .= __('Please enter your content', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) . '<br>';
    }
    echo json_encode(
            array(
                'status' => $status,
                'message' => $message,
            )
    );
} else {
    $status = 1;
    $admin_email = st()->get_option('email_admin_address');
    $body_email = "<html><body><h2>" . $subject_st . "</h2>";
    $body_email .= "<strong>" . __('Type Service', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) . "</strong>: " . $type_service . "<br/>" .
            "<strong>" . __('Name Service', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) . "</strong>: " . $name_service . "<br/>" .
            "<strong>" . __('Name customer', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) . "</strong>: " . $name_st . "<br/>" .
            "<strong>" . __('Email customer', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) . "</strong>: " . $email_st . "<br/>" .
            "<strong>" . __('Phone customer', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) . "</strong>: " . $phone_st . "<br/>" .
            "<strong>" . __('Trip Date', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) . "</strong>: " . $date . "<br/>" .
            "<strong>" . __('Number of Persons', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) . "</strong>: " . $pax . "<br/>" .
            "<strong>" . __('Cabin Requests', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) . "</strong>: " . $cabin . "<br/>" .
            "<strong>" . __('Notes', ST_TEXTDOMAIN) . "</strong>: " . $content_st . "<br/></html></body>";


    $multiple_to_recipients = array($email_owl, $email_st, $admin_email);
    $subject = $subject_st;
    $body = $body_email;
    $headers = 'From:' . $name_st . "<" . $email_st . ">" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: ' . $admin_email;
    $attachment = false;
    add_filter('wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type_sent_email');
    $check = wp_mail($multiple_to_recipients, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachment);
    remove_filter('wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type_sent_email');
    echo json_encode(
            array(
                'status' => $status,
                'message' => __('Thank you for contacting us!<br>We will be in contact shortly.', ST_TEXTDOMAIN),
            )
    );
}
die();
}
```

I tried to find a similar issue like that but without any result, any help will be appreciated

This is the code of the form

```
  <!-- <h4 class="heading"><?php echo __( 'Inquirement', ST_TEXTDOMAIN ) ?></h4> -->
    <div class="media form-st-send-mail">
        <form class="st_send-mail-form" method="GET" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="type_service" value="<?php echo esc_attr($type_service);?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="name_service" value="<?php the_title();?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="email_owl" value="<?php echo esc_attr($email_owl);?>">
            <div class="form-wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="name_st" placeholder="<?php echo __('Name *',ST_TEXTDOMAIN);?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" required class="form-control" name="email_st" placeholder="<?php echo __('Email *',ST_TEXTDOMAIN);?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="tel" required class="form-control" name="phone_st" placeholder="<?php echo __('Phone',ST_TEXTDOMAIN);?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="date" required class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="<?php echo __('Trip Date *',ST_TEXTDOMAIN);?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="number" required class="form-control" name="pax" placeholder="<?php echo __('Number of Persons *',ST_TEXTDOMAIN);?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group st_note_send_email">
                            <textarea name="cabin" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo __('Cabin Requests *',ST_TEXTDOMAIN);?>" style=""></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group st_note_send_email">
                            <textarea name="content_st" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php echo __('Notes',ST_TEXTDOMAIN);?>" style=""></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <input id="submit" type="submit"  name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-green upper font-small sent-email-st" value="<?php echo __('Send',ST_TEXTDOMAIN);?>">
                </div>
                <div class="message-wrapper-sendemail mt30"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with all the relevant code so we can see the problem. At the moment, we we can't see the code for the form, and we have extra code for the email that we don't need. Also include debugging details of what you have done to find the problem, for example, have you confirmed that your form is actually working, and the correct information is being submitted?

Comment: I just added it, Thanks a lot for your comment